# Invalid Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

Why the below is not a valid Lambda Expression?

```
 (Integer i) -> return "Alan" + i;
```

I expect it to be valid, But it is actually Invalid , Please Explain

Comment: Add the code around this expression, how are you actually using it?

Comment: What result do you expect when adding a String and an Integer?

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn I don't think that's a problem, the `+` operator between a string and "something else", implicitly calls the `toString()` method of that something else.

Comment: @Óscar López That’s true, and since i is an Integer and not an int, it will work. But it might be that OP is expecting something else. The surroundig code might answer that question.

Comment: A lambda expression is the implementation of a functional interface. A functional interface is an interface that contains precisely one abstract method. What functional interface does your lambda expression implement? And who told you it was invalid and what is the reason that it is invalid?

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn it would even work if it were just an `int`. Give it a try: `int i = 42; System.out.println("The answer is " + i);`

Answer (score 5):

It would be a valid lambda expression if you got the syntax right.

```
Function<Integer, String> f1 = (Integer i) -> { return "Alan" + i; };
Function<Integer, String> f2 = (Integer i) -> "Alan" + i;
Function<Integer, String> f3 = (i) -> "Alan" + i;
Function<Integer, String> f4 = i -> "Alan" + i;
```

A lambda body is either an expression (1) or a block (2) ([JLS-15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)).

(1)

<strike>`return`</strike>`expression`

`return` is never a part of an expression, it's a statement that controls execution flow ([JLS-14.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)).

(2)

To make it a block, braces are needed.

`{ return expression; }`

Comment: Of-course I have. And by the way, a functional interface does not have to be generic.

Comment: @Abra yes, it doesn't have to be generic. `Function<A, B>` is just the first thing that comes to mind when I see a lambda like that

Answer (score 1):

A bit more context is needed, about how you're using it. But for starters, try removing the `return`:

```
(Integer i) -> "Alan" + i
```

Also, the `Integer` declaration might be redundant - but we really need to see what you're trying to accomplish, and the expected type of the lambda. Are you sure that the lambda is supposed to return a `String`?